Mermaid style color/fill/stroke of an entity or attribute in ER diagram
reading the documentation https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/entityRelationshipDiagram.html#config-options
How is this style config applied? I would like to style the following diagram:
erDiagram
    CAR ||--o{ NAMED-DRIVER : allows
    CAR {
        string registrationNumber
        string make
        string model
    }
    PERSON ||--o{ NAMED-DRIVER : is
    PERSON {
        string firstName
        string lastName
        int age
    }


Explicitly I would like to color the registrationNumber. How is this possible using the fill option indicated in the documentation?
Here a link to the live editor:
Mermaid Live Example
THX

I am further investigating here: https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/2673 ; as of now I did not yet find a possibility to color specific attributes, but only all even or odd attributes globally

The styling options defined by Mermaid seem not to apply to the individual entity attributes.
But you can prepend your Mermaid code with a preamble containing a themeCSS configuration property. This can contain a CSS selector that relies on internals of the SVG being generated by the Mermaid renderer, specifically

the id attribute for an entity (entity- followed by the entity name followed another hyphen and more)
the ordering of the rect boxes (the 2nd and 3rd make up the first entity attribute).



<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs"></script>
<pre class="mermaid">
---
config:
  themeCSS: |
    [id|=entity-CAR] rect:nth-of-type(2),
    [id|=entity-CAR] rect:nth-of-type(3)
    { fill: yellow; }
---
erDiagram
    CAR ||--o{ NAMED-DRIVER : allows
    CAR {
        string registrationNumber
        string make
        string model
    }
    PERSON ||--o{ NAMED-DRIVER : is
    PERSON {
        string firstName
        string lastName
        int age
    }
</pre>




To make it run in the live editor, I had to adjust a bit:
https://www.mermaidchart.com/play?utm_source=mermaid_live_editor&utm_medium=banner_ad&utm_campaign=mermaid_ai#pako:eNp1UE1Lw0AQ_SvDQkDFPXlb8VCaHDwYJQEv3R7WdrId3A_ZjEjZ5r-7ErDU4DAww3uPeY_JYhf3KJSoqkyBWEHWAUppwQf0qIUqqxa3cAGv-_6H2czgTGxof_OAgYmPcr3qtpBwxyrwQcZB8vEDr-6uIcNAzimIyQSL95MWWx2m0lWlA6aajE3Gz2fLETidpIwZ2tVTU8u6e3xtOlBgnItf41mVzzlGThRs8bZUVsMUQ_vp3zAtJN684xIs33AzOs3jpen65_afIDReiJY5Bkojt8YvnZz5S1BgMBZ_3cX0DTOkfEg
You nailed it! THX! Would you mind adding this to your answer and I could accept?

It works in the live editor without any adjustment: https://www.mermaidchart.com/play?utm_source=mermaid_live_editor&utm_medium=banner_ad&utm_campaign=mermaid_ai#pako:eNqNkE9LxDAQxb_K0JMLzkVvEQ_Ltoc9WKUFL66H2J1mB_NH0hEpbb-7LRoRreCc3rz3S_LIkDXhSJnKEPEQD74JvmWjFgkgJ3K0q2sF44cB8MDH8Zq8sPS421aPEKkR5eWEoUXpX-jsYnP-f_hyk9gBWrZWQU_WhrcrmJbgsxTFnLWJ2iV4vgzGETEMUG5vihzzan9fVKBAL6e779yQlmU6iezN3MPwLLVw8OWre6K4Ajn9TGv2_F82-VMSd0VV35Z_lOLuB7bWqeXYSand2ptW_47YC2jzZU3Z9A5puZDb

Ah, alright. I was too fast and had problems because of the HTML tags. Thx
